# How to get a child nested list within a record using EFCore Linq

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-2.2

I have 3 Tables 1.Books 2.PO 3.Books_PO. I would like to pull a single PO record using books_po ref table but I want a list of books within that record.

```
 Books                    PO                 books_PO
ID   Name             ID    ponumber       poId    bookId
1    book1            3     1234           3       2
2    book2            5     2323           3       3
3    book3
```

My current query only brings back one book when I need a list of 2 books. If I return `.ToList()` I get 2 records for the PO but still one book. I am curious to know what I'm trying to do is possible?

```
ctx.books_po.Where(a => a.po.Id == 3).Include(b => b.Books).FirstorDefault();
```

Comment: `books_po` is one to one with `Books`. Not sure what your trying to achieve.

Comment: So to make sure I understand, are you saying you want, for example, a LINQ statement that would return a `List<Books>`of {"book2", "book3"} based on PoId 3?

Comment: When I query books_po with poId == 3, I want it to include bookId 2 and bookId 3 if that is possible.

Comment: Try: `ctx.books_po.Where(a => a.po.Id == 3).Include(b => b.Books).SelectMany(x => x.Books).ToList()`

Comment: And what exactly are you getting when you replace `FirstOrDefault()` with `ToList()`? You should be getting 2 `Book_PO` objects, right?

Comment: I'm curiuos why you are using `.FirstorDefault()`.  That will only give you a single result.

Comment: @Ray Can you try adding the `Include` right after the DbSet? `ctx.books_po.Include(b => b.Books).Where(a => a.poId == 3).FirstorDefault();`

Comment: @CaseyCrookston I prefer to get only a single PO and get all the books that were purchased within that PO

Comment: @Ray, but if your linq statement ends in `.FirstorDefault()', then the final result will always only contain one item.  You will never get multiple books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for GroupBy

```
var singleRecord = ctx.books_po
.Where(a => a.po.Id == 3)
.Include(b => b.Books)
.GroupBy(a => a.po, a => a.Books).FirstOrDefault();
```

You will get a single record with two fields singleRecord.Key and 
singleRecord.ToList() will be all the bookIds under that po (== 3)

Answer (score 0):

Why not using Books dbContexts instead of book_po ?

```
ctx.Books.Where(x => x.books_po.poId == 3).ToList();
```